# How to keep some text highlighted in any app when the app loses focus?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have two monitors and one monitor could be showing text in an app like a text editor, pdf reader, help file, web page etc.. Then I need to change focus to the app on the second monitor. Even if I have highlighted some text to remember my last position in the document, the highlight is lost when I switch focus to the app.

How do I keep the highlight from being lost when losing focus?

Comment: Losing text highlight when app loses focus is normal Windows behavior. Looking for a way to make hightlight stick

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on the title-bar, rather than in the text itself, when *regaining* focus, or use Alt-Tab. All applications on which I tried either of these kept highlighted sections as such even while not being the focused window. Some applications have a setting to ignore the first mouse-click when regaining focus, but that is not often needed.

A few applications do not correctly handle the Repaint event, and these will lose highlighting or even complete text when being moved to the front, but that is unusual.